# MySQLi, PHP - try { .... } catch (...) { .... } not working

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, try-catch, php-7

I'm trying to catch connection error on php7 using mysql, but it is not working...

I don't understand what is incorrect :S similar pieces of this code that i use is working as well...

It must be a basic detail what I'm forgetting...
I need to throw `$this->MyErrorFunction($e)`

Can someone help?

```
public function connect($credentialset) {
    #$this->driver = new \mysqli_driver();
    #$this->driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
    try {
        $this->conn->real_connect(
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['host'])       ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['host']        : ini_get("mysqli.default_host"),
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['user'])       ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['user']        : ini_get("mysqli.default_user"),
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['password'])   ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['password']    : ini_get("mysqli.default_pw"),
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['database'])   ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['database']    : "",
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['port'])       ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['port']        : ini_get("mysqli.default_port"),
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['socket'])     ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['socket']      : ini_get("mysqli.default_socket"),
                isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['flag'])       ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['flag']        : null
        );
        $charset = isset(self::$credentials[$credentialset]['charset']) ? self::$credentials[$credentialset]['charset'] : 'utf8mb4';
        $this->conn->set_charset($charset);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->MyErrorFunction($e);
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'myinvaliduser'@'10.241.84.65' (using password: YES) in /oxygen-v2/php-bin/datadrivers/mysqlz/mysqlz.php on line 77

Answer (score 0):

\ó/
i was sure that error was only a stupid thing!

Solved replacing this piece of code:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->MyErrorFunction($e);
}
```

by this code:

```
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    $this->MyErrorFunction($e);
}
```

In place of `Exception`, i need to throw `mysqli_sql_exception` in the main namespace "`\`"